# Powershell console Font settings registry locatoin

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 production release and I see that font settings (face, size) are being persisted when I change them by right-clicking on title bar -> properties but I can't find any accesses to registry using Microsoft's Process Monitor (by Mark Russinovich).

Question: How does powershell handle its font settings?

Not a question: How do I change powershell font settings?

Not an answer: hkcu:\console, hkcu:\console\%SystemRoot%

Comment: This question is more suited for [su].

Comment: If console application launched from `.lnk` file, then properties are persisted in that `.lnk` file.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider You're right, I'll wait for someone to delete (deleting myself runs the risk of getting banned)

Answer (score -2):

See the [Change PowerShell console font size with a cmdlet](https://4sysops.com/archives/change-powershell-console-font-size-with-cmdlet)

Comment: In my question, see: "not a question" section

Comment: Don't be lame & ridiculous. Check out the scripts source code to see how it does it, and where this is store it, which you would find it out yourself if you didn't just glance it: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/cb72e4e6-4a68-4a2e-89b7-cc43a860349e

Comment: So ?  You want it to use registry so badly ? Do you know what you want ?